# Installing ArangoDB on Windows Server 2008

Tags: crash, kernel, windows-server-2008, arangodb

I'm having difficulty getting Arango 1.4.9 working on my Windows 2008 Standard (SP2) server. It's a fresh install. When I try to start Arango Server I receive this message:

> The procedure entry point TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

I have tried both the 64bit and 32bit versions. I have run the installer as an administrator and vice versa. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it 2008 or 2008r2?

Answer (score 3):

TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive is from a newer Windows API. The Windows 2008r2 build uses newer Windows API features such as SRW (Slim/Reader Writer) API to improve performance. These are not available in Windows Server 2008.

I assume that you must recompile for Windows 2008 or ask for a suitable binary in the support forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb).