# mysqld.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: mysql, windows, dll, entry-point, kernel32

I installed MySQL version "**mysql-5.7.10-winx64**" on Windows Server 2008 x64 Standard Edition, but I have a problem. When I start `mysqld.exe` from CMD (Command Prompt) I always have this error:

> The procedure entry point TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.

Comment: I've fixed the grammar and removed some extraneous comments. I also removed the link to the image. URLs change so including the error text in the question (which you already did) is better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing ArangoDB on Windows Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073538/installing-arangodb-on-windows-server-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,642417,642538#msg-642538) on the MySQL forums which cites the [MySQL supported platforms](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html) page, you need Windows 2008 **R2** to run that version of MySQL.

I encountered the exact same error attempting to install MongoDB 3.4.3 on a Windows 2008 server when I downloaded the wrong version of the installer.